# How can I get the user id associated with a login on Linux?

Tags: c, unix

Short version: I want a way to run `somefunction("username")` and have it return the user ID associated with `username`. For example `somefunction("root")` would return `0`.

I'm writing a server program that could potentially use low-numbered ports, so it has to start as root. Obviously, I don't want it to run as root, so the plan is to let users specify what user the program should run as. The problem is that `setuid()` requires a user ID and I don't know how to look up a user ID from a login name. I looked in `unistd.h` and it seems to only have functions for finding info about the current user.

I know I could just open `/etc/passwd`, but I'd rather not when there's bound to be a function for this.

Comment: The answer gave you a fish; here's how to fish: `man -k -s 3 password` and `man man` in case you don't know what the first command means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically getting UID and GID from username in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1009254/608639)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want [`getpwnam`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam).

Here's a complete example I just wrote:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uid_t name_to_uid(char const *name)
{
  if (!name)
    return -1;
  long const buflen = sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX);
  if (buflen == -1)
    return -1;
  // requires c99
  char buf[buflen];
  struct passwd pwbuf, *pwbufp;
  if (0 != getpwnam_r(name, &pwbuf, buf, buflen, &pwbufp)
      || !pwbufp)
    return -1;
  return pwbufp->pw_uid;
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%i\n", name_to_uid(argv[1]));
}
```

Comment: `void main` is wrong; it should be `int main`. And you should check the value of `argc` before accessing `argv[1]`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It's short for purposes of example. Bounds checking and error handling outside the name_to_uid function is beyond the scope of the answer.

Comment: `int main` is shorter than `void main`, and had considerable virtue of being correct.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler approach will be:

```
#include <pwd.h>

#define INVALID_UID  -1
uid_t getuid_byName(const char *name)
{
    if(name) {
        struct passwd *pwd = getpwnam(name); /* don't free, see getpwnam() for details */
        if(pwd) return pwd->pw_uid;
    }
  return INVALID_UID;
}
```