# How to drop root privileges on linux in C?

Tags: c, linux

I'd like to fork and exec and program as a non root user while the parent retains root permissions.

pseudo code:

```
  pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) {
      if (RunAsUser(ConvertStringToUserId("John")) == false) {
          stop();
      }
      if (RunAsUser(ConvertStringToUserId("admin")) == true) {
          stop();
      }
      CreateProcess();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `setuid()` in the child process?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropping root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357737/dropping-root-privileges)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to drop privileges in C code, use the function `setuid`.

Comment: To get the uid for setuid will I need to search /etc/passwd?

Comment: If you need to adjust groups, remember to do that before changing the user privileges.

Comment: To get the UID for `setuid()`, use `getpwnam()`, which logically searches `/etc/passwd` -- unless you've got other name services (LDAP, etc) in use as well or instead.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009254/programatically-getting-uid-and-gid-from-username-in-unix to know how to get `uid` from `username`

Answer (score 0):

Get your program to invoke the child process as

```
sudo -u user /path/to/externalprogram
```

instead of just

```
/path/to/externalprogram
```

Comment: no. OP wants to **DROP** root privileges, not gain them.

Comment: That IS how to drop root privileges. If you're root, running `sudo -u user prog` will run `prog` as user `user`.

Comment: Spawn a new process that basically only does a `seduid()` call?

Comment: But OP wants to do it on a forked child, not on the entire process.

Comment: Yes. If his program runs `sudo -u user prog` as a child process, that child process will run as `user`.

Comment: Of the two answers this is the most straightforward one. As I'll be collecting the user name not the uid(whatever that is.) sudo makes the most sense. I would prefer to use setsid but it's impossible to find a way to translate a username to a uid.

Comment: @user1450181 there is, see my comment on Wojtek Surowka's answer. `sudo`, or better `su` because `sudo` may not be installed, makes sense if you want to run a different application. Beware that you are actually forking three time: first fork to shell, which forks to sudo, which forks to the target process.